# Log file format/structure explanation

Tags: iis, logfiles

Hi I am using hadoop to process log files.

Suppose i had a log file with the data something like below

```
2012-11-04 23:00:04 10.1.151.54 GET /_layouts/1033/js/global.js v=5 443 - 10.1.151.61 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.2+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/15.0.864.0+Safari/535.2 200 0 0 31
2012-11-04 23:00:04 10.1.151.54 GET /_layouts/1033/styles/css/topnav.css v=1 443 - 10.1.151.61 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.2+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/15.0.864.0+Safari/535.2 200 0 0 62
2012-11-04 23:00:07 10.1.151.54 GET /pages/index.aspx - 80 - 10.1.151.59 - 200 0 64 374
2012-11-04 23:00:07 10.1.151.52 GET /pages/index.aspx - 80 - 10.1.151.59 - 200 0 64 374
```

In the above lines we can found date,method(GET/POST) etc.,

I am unable to understand the remaining stuff in each line clearly and confused , can anyone explain/elaborate each and every part of the line in detail.

Comment: So, you're asking us to tell you the format of an arbitrary file without telling us anything about where it came from?

Comment: @joe:Actually i just simply got those files to process using hadoop and store the data in a required format(according to IP/url etc.,). After enquiry i came to know that these are log files generated in IIS server on .net something...

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/be22e074-72f8-46da-bb7e-e27877c85bca.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @Joe:Thanks really for u r help,all my problem is i am confusing in mapping the respective IIS terms to the data in the above mentioned lines, if you dont mind please that would be really great if you map those terms for the above one of the lines

Comment: The logfile contains a header line that says what each field is, for example: `#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status cs(User-Agent)`